# CSS dropdown menu to open on click and/or on hover for iOS

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, css, ipad

I have a CSS dropdown list that opens on hover, which creates a problem when somebody is using an iOS device like an iPad or iPhone.  I created a rough jFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7vtWy/1/

If I use an Android device with chrome, it works great...clicking the main menu item brings up the dropdown list.  On iOS, nothing.  Is there a way that I can make it so that if there is a mobile device, the dropdown will display on main menu click since there is no such thing as hover?

**HTML**

```
<header>        
<nav role="navigation" class="clearfix">
        <ul id="nav-site">
            <li>
                <span class="arrow">Shop</span>
                <div class="dropdown_1column">
                    <div class="mainbox clearfix">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="main-category"><a href="new-products/">New Arrivals</a></li>
                            <li class="main-category"><a href="gifts-under-100/">Gifts Under $100</a></li>
                            <li class="main-category"><a href="staff-favorites/">Staff Favorites</a></li>
                            <li class="main-category"><a href="made-in-the-usa/">Made in the USA</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
header nav { text-transform: uppercase; width: 980px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 15px;}
header nav a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
header nav li { float: left; display: block; position: relative; z-index: 999; }

header nav #nav-site { float: left; }
header nav #nav-site li { padding: 0 10px 3px 0; }
header nav .arrow:hover { cursor: pointer; }
header nav #nav-account { float: right; }
header nav #nav-account li { margin: 0 0 3px 10px; }
header nav #nav-account .cart span { font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px; padding: 2px 4px; display: block; position: absolute; top: 01px; left: 48px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; background: #edeb2b; display: block; }
header nav #nav-account .cart span:hover { background: #f6f6f6; }

header nav .dropdown_1column { position: absolute; left: -999em; width: 980px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 13px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: 1px; }
header nav li:hover .dropdown_1column {left: auto; top: auto; }
header nav .dropdown_1column .mainbox { background: #edeb2b; border: 4px solid #000; }
header nav .dropdown_1column ul { width: 161px; float: left; letter-spacing: 0; height: 235px; border-right: 1px solid #d4d220; }
header nav .dropdown_1column ul.last { border: none; }
header nav #nav-site .dropdown_1column li { float: none; margin: 0; font-size: 12px; }
header nav #nav-site .dropdown_1column li.main-category { font-weight: 700; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 13px; }
header nav .dropdown_1column a { display: block; padding: 5px 10px; }
header nav .dropdown_1column a:hover { background: #d4d220; }
header nav #nav-site .dropdown_1column .popular { padding: 10px; }
header nav .dropdown_1column .popular a { display: inline; padding: 0; }
header nav .dropdown_1column .popular a:hover { background: #d4d220; }
header nav .dropdown_1column li.main-category a:hover { background: none; color: #363636; }

header nav .dropdown_1column_right { position: absolute; left: -999em; font-weight: 400; font-size: 13px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: 1px; }
header nav .dropdown_1column_right span { position: absolute; right: 10px; padding: 0 4px; background: #d4d220; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; }
header nav li:hover .dropdown_1column_right {left: auto; right: -49px; top: auto; }
header nav .dropdown_1column_right ul {letter-spacing: 0; background: #edeb2b; border: 4px solid #000; width: 175px; }
header nav #nav-account .dropdown_1column_right li { float: none; margin: 0; }
header nav .dropdown_1column_right a { display: block; padding: 5px 10px; }
header nav .dropdown_1column_right a:hover { background: #d4d220; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of hover, I'm using jQuery to `bind()` to the  `touchstart` and `touchend` functions. In short, the `:hover` responsible for showing the drop-down was changed to `.hover`.
In your mobile environments, this will translate to "when user is touching your nav item, the dopdown will show. When they release their finger, it will disappear."

Mind you, alterations to make the UX better may include "click/tap to dismiss" or something similar.

Also, if this is to be used on desktop enviornments as well, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` will work fine. [AFIK, in Mobile Safari as well](http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html)

#### In comes the jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('header nav li').bind({
        'touchstart': function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover')
        },
            'touchend': function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover')
        }
    });
});
```

> [**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/gvyKB/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/gvyKB/3/)